# extracting specific content from html page

Tags: python

Suppose I have an html page source like:

```
<p><font face="Arial" color="#400040"><small><strong>

<a href="some_link">description</a>: </strong>some text.</small></font></p>
```

I want to just extract the "description part?
How do I do this. I think there is a very pythonic way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  Then:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_text)
description = soup.find('a').string
```

You may need to modify the last line to uniquely identify your a tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BeautifulSoup, see this example from the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '''<p><font face="Arial" color="#400040"><small><strong>

<a href="some_link">description</a>: </strong>some text.</small></font></p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<p><font face="Arial" color="#400040"><small><strong><a href="some_link">description</a>: </strong>some text.</small></font></p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.find('a', text=True)
u'description'
```

If you have multiple tags, which most probably will be the case, you could do:

```
>>> for link in soup.findAll('a'):
...     print link.text
```